# How do I add image to html borders

Tags: html, css

Good day everyone :) I'm new to Stackoverflow.. My question is how do you add an image to a border? I've searched everywhere on how to achieve this but no or zero luck at all.. I know it's possible and would really like to know how, I'm new to web development and right now I'm working on my skill-sets on furthering my skills, I've seen on this site [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEomE.jpg) that they've done it.. If anyone know please tell me or show me a code on how to do this.. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in multiple ways.

Option 1:
User border-image property.

```
#borderimg { 
    -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
}
```

Option 2:
Use Background image for the section and add required padding all sides.

```
div {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```